# react native redux periodic fetching

Tags: react-native, react-redux

i am trying to periodically fetch notifications from my API in my react-native app. I tried to use setInterval in my Root Component. I only want to fetch notifications if the user is logged in, but when i try to get my currently signed in user that is stored within my store it is always undefined.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppProvider />
    </Provider>
  )
}

function AppProvider(){
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  // fetch notifications every minute
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("fetching notifications")
      dispatch(fetchNotifications())
    }, 60 000)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return (
    <ApplicationProvider 
      mapping={eva.mapping} 
      theme={theme}
    >
      <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />

      <RootNavigation />
    </ApplicationProvider>
  )
}
```

In the following block you can see a part of my fetch notifications function

```
export const fetchNotifications = (): AppThunk => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const signedInUser = getState().app.signedInUser

  // abort if user is not logged in or notifications are already fetching
  if (signedInUser === undefined || getState().notifications.isFetching){
    console.log("aborting fetching")
    console.log(signedInUser)
    return 
  }

  try {
    // fetch notifications
  } catch (err){
    // handle error while fetching
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that the signedIn user is always set to undefined (the default state) even though i have already signed in and the signed in user state is set. It seems that the function used in setInterval always uses the default app state. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: one thing is not clear is that after the log in, is `app.signedInUser` filled ? can you print out to make sure first ?

Comment: yes it is filled, i do use it to display my username etc., that is working as expected